# Why does my JSON update for one API but not the other?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

The answer to this question is most likely "Go to bed and you'll see the error in the morning", yet the frustration the below snippet is causing me is not going to allow that to happen.

As you can see in the below snippet. I have various `tables` with an `NVD3` chart and some just plain `p` tags that contain data from multiple **API**.

The issue I am having is when updating the **API URL** using the `datepicker` (it allows the `date` to be set in the **API URL** to return data from the selected period) all of the data updates, **except for the table** class `badTable` (it's the one in red). What have I done wrong or missed?

Can someone please look at this and hopefully point out the solution that I am clearly missing?

```js
$(function() {
  var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
  var end = moment();
  let dateDates = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ',' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  let defaultSummaryUrl = `https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=API.get&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=${dateDates}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`;
  let defaultPagesUrl = `https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=Actions.getPageTitles&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=${dateDates}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`;
  let defaultDeviceUrl = `https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=DevicesDetection.getType&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=${dateDates}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`;
  let defaultBrowserUrl = `https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=DevicesDetection.getBrowsers&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=${dateDates}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`;
  let defaultOSUrl = `https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=DevicesDetection.getOsFamilies&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=${dateDates}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`;

  summaryAnalytics(defaultSummaryUrl);
  pagesAnalytics(defaultPagesUrl);
  deviceAnalytics(defaultDeviceUrl);
  browserAnalytics(defaultBrowserUrl);
  OSAnalytics(defaultOSUrl);

  $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 90 Days': [moment().subtract(89, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
  }, function(start, end) {

    let dates = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ',' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    let summaryUrl = `https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=API.get&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=${dates}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`;
    let pagesUrl = `https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=Actions.getPageTitles&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=${dateDates}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`;
    let deviceUrl = `https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=DevicesDetection.getType&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=${dates}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`;
    let browserUrl = `https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=DevicesDetection.getBrowsers&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=${dates}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`;
    let OSUrl = `https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=DevicesDetection.getOsFamilies&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=${dates}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`;

    summaryAnalytics(summaryUrl);
    pagesAnalytics(pagesUrl);
    deviceAnalytics(deviceUrl);
    browserAnalytics(browserUrl);
    OSAnalytics(OSUrl);


  });

  function summaryAnalytics(summaryUrl) {
    $.getJSON(summaryUrl, (data) => {
      let visitors = 0;
      let uniq_visitors = 0;
      let pageviews = 0;
      let uniq_pageviews = 0;
      let actions = 0;
      let outlinks = 0;
      let bounces = 0;
      let avgtime = 0;
      let dayCount = 0;

      for (i in data) {

        if (data[i].nb_visits) {
          visitors += data[i].nb_visits;
        }
        if (data[i].nb_uniq_visitors) {
          uniq_visitors += data[i].nb_uniq_visitors;
        }
        if (data[i].nb_pageviews) {
          pageviews += data[i].nb_pageviews;
        }
        if (data[i].nb_uniq_pageviews) {
          uniq_pageviews += data[i].nb_uniq_pageviews;
        }
        if (data[i].nb_actions) {
          actions += data[i].nb_actions;
        }
        if (data[i].nb_outlinks) {
          outlinks += data[i].nb_outlinks;
        }
        if (data[i].bounce_count) {
          bounces += data[i].bounce_count;
        }
        if (data[i].avg_time_on_site) {
          avgtime += data[i].avg_time_on_site;
          dayCount++;
        }
      }

      $("#visitors").html(visitors);
      $("#uniq_visitors").html(uniq_visitors);
      $("#pageviews").html(pageviews);
      $("#uniq_pageviews").html(uniq_pageviews);
      $("#actions").html(actions);
      $("#outlinks").html(outlinks);
      $("#bounces").html(bounces);
      $("#avgtime").html(Math.round(avgtime / dayCount));
      $("#uniq_visitors_percent").html(Math.round(uniq_visitors / (visitors / 100)));
      $("#pageviews_percent").html(Math.round(pageviews / (visitors / 100)));
      $("#uniq_pageviews_percent").html(Math.round(uniq_pageviews / (pageviews / 100)));
      $("#actions_percent").html(Math.round(actions / (pageviews / 100)));
      $("#outlinks_percent").html(Math.round(outlinks / (pageviews / 100)));
      $("#bounces_percent").html(Math.round(bounces / (pageviews / 100)));

    });
    d3.json(summaryUrl, (page_data) => {

      var lc_visits = page_data;
      var lc_unique_visits = page_data;
      var lc_page_views = page_data;
      var lc_unique_page_views = page_data;
      var lc_actions = page_data;
      var lc_outlinks = page_data;
      var lc_bounces = page_data;

      var result_visits = Object.keys(lc_visits)
        .map(k => [new Date(k).getTime(), (lc_visits[k].nb_visits || 0)]);
      lc_visits = {
        "key": "Visits",
        "values": result_visits
      };

      var result_unique_visits = Object.keys(lc_unique_visits)
        .map(k => [new Date(k).getTime(), (lc_unique_visits[k].nb_uniq_visitors || 0)]);
      lc_unique_visits = {
        "key": "Unique Visits",
        "values": result_unique_visits
      };

      var result_page_views = Object.keys(lc_page_views)
        .map(k => [new Date(k).getTime(), (lc_page_views[k].nb_pageviews || 0)]);
      lc_page_views = {
        "key": "Views",
        "values": result_page_views
      };

      var result_unique_views = Object.keys(lc_unique_page_views)
        .map(k => [new Date(k).getTime(), (lc_unique_page_views[k].nb_uniq_pageviews || 0)]);
      lc_unique_page_views = {
        "key": "Unique Views",
        "values": result_unique_views
      };

      var result_actions = Object.keys(lc_actions)
        .map(k => [new Date(k).getTime(), (lc_actions[k].nb_actions || 0)]);
      lc_actions = {
        "key": "Actions",
        "values": result_actions
      };

      var result_outlinks = Object.keys(lc_outlinks)
        .map(k => [new Date(k).getTime(), (lc_outlinks[k].nb_outlinks || 0)]);
      lc_outlinks = {
        "key": "Exits",
        "values": result_outlinks
      };

      var result_bounces = Object.keys(lc_bounces)
        .map(k => [new Date(k).getTime(), (lc_bounces[k].bounce_count || 0)]);
      lc_bounces = {
        "key": "Bounces",
        "values": result_bounces
      };

      var data = [];
      data.push(lc_visits);
      data.push(lc_unique_visits);
      data.push(lc_page_views);
      data.push(lc_unique_page_views);
      data.push(lc_actions);
      data.push(lc_outlinks);
      data.push(lc_bounces);

      nv.addGraph(function() {

        var chart = nv.models.lineChart()
          .margin({
            left: 45,
            right: 30
          })
          .x(function(d) {
            return d[0]
          })
          .y(function(d) {
            return d[1]
          })
          .color(['#007be8', '#ea4354', '#eb532e', '#6feabb', '#673ab7', '#4caf50', '#f44336'])
          .useInteractiveGuideline(true);


        chart.xAxis
          .tickFormat(function(d) {
            return d3.time.format('%m/%d/%y')(new Date(d))
          });

        chart.yAxis
          .tickFormat(d3.format('d'));

        chart.yAxis.tickPadding(15);
        chart.xAxis.tickPadding(15);

        chart.interactiveLayer.tooltip.headerFormatter(function(d) {
          return d;
        });

        d3.select('#summaryChart svg')
          .datum(data)
          .transition().duration(500)
          .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

        $('#summaryChart').data('chart', chart);

        return chart;
      });
    });
  };
  // END Summary Chart

  //Campaign Table
  function pagesAnalytics(pagesUrl) {
    $.getJSON(pagesUrl, (campaignPages_data) => {
      Array.prototype.groupBy = function(key) {
        var path = key.split('.');
        var result = {};
        try {
          this.forEach(function(item) {
            // es6: path.reduce((a, b) => a[b], item)
            type = path.reduce(function(a, b) {
              return a[b]
            }, item) || 'null';
            if (!result[type])
              result[type] = [];
            result[type].push(item);
          });
          return result;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return {};
        }
      };

      function getPropertySum(key, arr) {
        return arr.reduce((a, b) => (key in b ? a + b[key] : a), 0)
      }
      let flattenArr = [].concat.apply([], Object.values(campaignPages_data));
      let groups = flattenArr.groupBy('label');
      let table = document.getElementById('campaignTable');
      table.innerHTML = '';
      Object.keys(groups).forEach(function(label) {
        let row = document.createElement('tr');
        let logw = document.createElement('td');
        let logo = document.createElement('img');
        let lab = document.createElement('span');
        let nbv = document.createElement('td');
        let nbu = document.createElement('td');
        let nba = document.createElement('td');
        let nbb = document.createElement('td');
        logw.className = "subscriber subscriber-fixed-alone fixed-cell";
        logo.className = "table_image_icon";
        lab.className = "stat number text-center";
        nbv.className = "stat number text-center";
        nbu.className = "stat number text-center";
        nba.className = "stat number text-center";
        nbb.className = "stat number text-center";

        row.appendChild(logw);
        row.appendChild(nbv);
        row.appendChild(nbu);
        row.appendChild(nba);
        row.appendChild(nbb);

        logw.appendChild(logo);
        logw.appendChild(lab);
        logo.src = 'https://discovrbookings.com/wp-content/themes/discovr-application/assets/img/campaigns/ads-icon.svg';
        lab.innerHTML = label;
        nbv.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_visits', groups[label]);
        nbu.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_uniq_visitors', groups[label]);
        nba.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_actions', groups[label]);
        nbb.innerHTML = getPropertySum('bounce_count', groups[label]);
        table.appendChild(row);
      });
    });
  };
  // END Campaign Table


  //Device Type
  function deviceAnalytics(deviceUrl) {
    $.getJSON(deviceUrl, (device_data) => {
      Array.prototype.groupBy = function(key) {
        var path = key.split('.');
        var result = {};
        try {
          this.forEach(function(item) {
            // es6: path.reduce((a, b) => a[b], item)
            type = path.reduce(function(a, b) {
              return a[b]
            }, item) || 'null';
            if (!result[type])
              result[type] = [];
            result[type].push(item);
          });
          return result;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return {};
        }
      };

      function getPropertySum(key, arr) {
        return arr.reduce((a, b) => (key in b ? a + b[key] : a), 0)
      }
      let flattenArr = [].concat.apply([], Object.values(device_data));
      let groups = flattenArr.groupBy('label');
      let table = document.getElementById('deviceTable');
      table.innerHTML = '';
      Object.keys(groups).forEach(function(label) {
        let row = document.createElement('tr');
        let logw = document.createElement('td');
        let logo = document.createElement('img');
        let lab = document.createElement('span');
        let nbv = document.createElement('td');
        let nbu = document.createElement('td');
        let nba = document.createElement('td');
        let nbb = document.createElement('td');
        logw.className = "month subscriber subscriber-fixed-alone fixed-cell";
        logo.className = "table_image_icon";
        lab.className = "stat number text-center";
        nbv.className = "stat number text-center";
        nbu.className = "stat number text-center";
        nba.className = "stat number text-center";
        nbb.className = "stat number text-center";

        row.appendChild(logw);
        row.appendChild(nbv);
        row.appendChild(nbu);
        row.appendChild(nba);
        row.appendChild(nbb);

        logw.appendChild(logo);
        logw.appendChild(lab);
        logo.src = 'https://discovrbookings.com/wp-content/themes/discovr-application/assets/img/device-icons/' + label + '.png';
        lab.innerHTML = label;
        nbv.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_visits', groups[label]);
        nbu.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_uniq_visitors', groups[label]);
        nba.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_actions', groups[label]);
        nbb.innerHTML = getPropertySum('bounce_count', groups[label]);
        table.appendChild(row);
      });
    });
  };
  // END Device Type


  //Browser Type
  function browserAnalytics(browserUrl) {
    $.getJSON(browserUrl, (browser_data) => {
      Array.prototype.groupBy = function(key) {
        var path = key.split('.');
        var result = {};
        try {
          this.forEach(function(item) {
            type = path.reduce(function(a, b) {
              return a[b]
            }, item) || 'null';
            if (!result[type])
              result[type] = [];
            result[type].push(item);
          });
          return result;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return {};
        }
      };

      function getPropertySum(key, arr) {
        return arr.reduce((a, b) => (key in b ? a + b[key] : a), 0)
      }
      let flattenArr = [].concat.apply([], Object.values(browser_data));
      let groups = flattenArr.groupBy('label');
      let table = document.getElementById('browserTable');

      table.innerHTML = '';
      Object.keys(groups).forEach(function(label) {
        let row = document.createElement('tr');
        let logw = document.createElement('td');
        let logo = document.createElement('img');
        let lab = document.createElement('span');
        let nbv = document.createElement('td');
        let nbu = document.createElement('td');
        let nba = document.createElement('td');
        let nbb = document.createElement('td');
        logw.className = "month subscriber subscriber-fixed-alone fixed-cell";
        logo.className = "table_image_icon";
        lab.className = "stat number text-center";
        nbv.className = "stat number text-center";
        nbu.className = "stat number text-center";
        nba.className = "stat number text-center";
        nbb.className = "stat number text-center";

        row.appendChild(logw);
        row.appendChild(nbv);
        row.appendChild(nbu);
        row.appendChild(nba);
        row.appendChild(nbb);

        logw.appendChild(logo);
        logw.appendChild(lab);
        logoProperty = getPropertySum('logo', groups[label]);
        var logoPropSplit = logoProperty.split("/");
        var logoName = logoPropSplit[logoPropSplit.length - 1];
        logo.src = 'https://discovrbookings.com/wp-content/themes/discovr-application/assets/img/browser-icons/' + logoName;
        lab.innerHTML = label;
        nbv.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_visits', groups[label]);
        nbu.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_uniq_visitors', groups[label]);
        nba.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_actions', groups[label]);
        nbb.innerHTML = getPropertySum('bounce_count', groups[label]);
        table.appendChild(row);
      });
    });
  };
  // END Browser Type

  //Operating System Type
  function OSAnalytics(OSUrl) {
    $.getJSON(OSUrl, (OS_data) => {
      Array.prototype.groupBy = function(key) {
        var path = key.split('.');
        var result = {};
        try {
          this.forEach(function(item) {
            type = path.reduce(function(a, b) {
              return a[b]
            }, item) || 'null';
            if (!result[type])
              result[type] = [];
            result[type].push(item);
          });
          return result;
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err);
          return {};
        }
      };

      function getPropertySum(key, arr) {
        return arr.reduce((a, b) => (key in b ? a + b[key] : a), 0)
      }
      let flattenArr = [].concat.apply([], Object.values(OS_data));
      let groups = flattenArr.groupBy('label');
      let table = document.getElementById('OSTable');
      table.innerHTML = '';
      Object.keys(groups).forEach(function(label) {
        let row = document.createElement('tr');
        let logw = document.createElement('td');
        let logo = document.createElement('img');
        let lab = document.createElement('span');
        let nbv = document.createElement('td');
        let nbu = document.createElement('td');
        let nba = document.createElement('td');
        let nbb = document.createElement('td');
        logw.className = "month subscriber subscriber-fixed-alone fixed-cell";
        logo.className = "table_image_icon";
        lab.className = "stat number text-center";
        nbv.className = "stat number text-center";
        nbu.className = "stat number text-center";
        nba.className = "stat number text-center";
        nbb.className = "stat number text-center";

        row.appendChild(logw);
        row.appendChild(nbv);
        row.appendChild(nbu);
        row.appendChild(nba);
        row.appendChild(nbb);

        logw.appendChild(logo);
        logw.appendChild(lab);
        // Get the logo property and use split on the string
        logoProperty = getPropertySum('logo', groups[label]);
        var logoPropSplit = logoProperty.split("/");
        var logoName = logoPropSplit[logoPropSplit.length - 1];
        logo.src = 'https://discovrbookings.com/wp-content/themes/discovr-application/assets/img/os-icons/' + logoName;
        lab.innerHTML = label;
        nbv.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_visits', groups[label]);
        nbu.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_uniq_visitors', groups[label]);
        nba.innerHTML = getPropertySum('nb_actions', groups[label]);
        nbb.innerHTML = getPropertySum('bounce_count', groups[label]);
        table.appendChild(row);
      });
    });
  };
  // END Operating System Type
}); //End of Function
```

```css
.table_image_icon {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

.overview p {
  border: 1px solid;
  width: 24%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#summaryChart svg {
  height: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}

.badTable {
  border: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/2.1.27/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-daterangepicker/2.1.27/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/nvd3/1.8.6/nv.d3.js"></script>

<div id="reportrange">
  <span>Choose Dates</span>
</div>

<div class="overview">
  <p><span id="visitors"></span> visits</p>
  <p><span id="uniq_visitors"></span> unique visits</p>
  <p><span id="pageviews"></span> views</p>
  <p><span id="uniq_pageviews"></span> unique views</p>
  <p><span id="bounces"></span> bounces</p>
  <p><span id="actions"></span> actions</p>
  <p><span id="outlinks"></span> exits</p>
  <p><span id="avgtime"></span> seconds</p>

  <div id="summaryChart" class="line-chart text-center" data-x-grid="false">
    <svg></svg>
  </div>

  <table border="1" class="badTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>WHY WON'T IT UPDATE WHEN CHANGING DATES???</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="campaignTable"></tbody>
  </table>

  <table border="1">

    <tbody id="deviceTable"></tbody>
  </table>

  <table border="1">

    <tbody id="browserTable"></tbody>
  </table>
  <table border="1">

    <tbody id="OSTable"></tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: Make sure you read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This should help both sides.

Comment: @Vanna Thanks, I get that. This question is much more a longshot for some fresh eyes that can hopefully identify a simple mistake that I have made. The example is pretty straightforward so I'll leave as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `pagesUrl` you are using `${dateDates}` instead of `${dates}`

Comment: I don't know whether to laugh or cry. Hours of stripping things away and there it is. Thank you so much!!!